# What's wrong with this LEAN proof?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, coq

I'm learning to use the [LEAN theorem prover](https://leanprover.github.io/) and I got stuck in a proof of a simple fact in first-order logic:
$$ p(x) \rightarrow \forall x p(x) $$
My code is the following:

> variables (A : Type) (p q : A → Prop)
>
> example (x : A) : p x → (∀ x, p x) :=
>
> assume H : p x,
>
> take x : A,
>
> show p x, from H

but it keeps saying that H has type p x_1, instead of what I expected, which is type p x.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Please check [tour] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is not true, that's why you cannot prove it. If we assume your example is true (which we do using the `sorry` tactic), then we can prove `false`. The proof goes as follows. We first pick `x` to be `0` and `p` to be the property that a number `n` is equal to `0`. So `p x` is `p 0` is `0 == 0` which is obviously true. Your example now provides us with the proof that `p` holds for all numbers. We pick `1`, which is a contradiction because `0 <> 1`.

```
variables (A : Type) (p : A → Prop)

lemma lma (x : A) : p x → (∀ x', p x') :=
  assume H : p x,
  take x' : A,
  sorry

lemma inconsistent : false :=
  assert h : 0 == 0 → (∀ x, x == 0), from (lma num (λ n, n==0) 0),
  assert e : 1 == 0, begin
    refine (h _ 1), 
    reflexivity
  end,
  show false, by cases e
```

The formula that you posted is also false in first order logic, even `∀ x, p x → (∀ x, p x)` is not a true statement. Note that your example is different from the true statement `(∀ x, p x) → (∀ x, p x)`.

The error message that you see stems from the fact that you are trying to use the hypothesis `p x` where the hypothesis `p x'` is expected (you are confusing the `x`es)